# ORA-24756: transaction does not exist

Tags: oracle, distributed, database-administration, 2phase-commit

Am doing a distributed update and I get this ORA-24756 error:

```
 DISTRIB TRAN bea1.67AA54355C4A74ECDEE0
is local tran 6.42.332492 (hex=06.2a.512cc)
insert pending prepared tran, scn=8151148567799 (hex=769.d6509cf7)
Wed Jan 30 16:45:02 EAT 2015
Errors in file /oradata/sfapdb/bdump/sfapdb_reco_2739.trc:
ORA-24756: transaction does not exist

oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAExceptionSQLException: ORA-24756: transaction does not exist.
```

This error is from a failed  two-phase commit
I also found out there are some records (trans_id = "6.42.332492") in SYS.PENDING_TRANS$/ SYS.PENDING_SESSION$/dba_2pc_pending with "prepare" status. This transaction is launched from a Weblogic Server via JDBC.\
How do I resolve this ORA-24756 error?

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_24756.htm exactly the same id, that's a bit odd.

Comment: Can it happen due to difference of version of JDBC driver?
it happens inojdbc6, might be it won't happen in ojdbc8 libraries or it is not realted?